# Android: Help to handle Screen Orientation

Tags: android, orientation

I am working on an Android application that is dynamically creating controls. I done this type Coding.

```
TextView lblTitle = new TextView(myContext);
relLayoutHeader.addView(lblTitle);

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 
   if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
       lblTitle.settext("LandScape");
   } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
       lblTitle.settext("Portrait");
}
```

in  manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

when i am change orientation from portrait to landscape it works good. But from landscape to portrait application is crash down. force closed.

Any suggestion for my code?????

Comment: If you say that it's crashing, please add your logcat.. You're bound to get a crash log whenever your app crashes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialize you view at `onConfigurationChanged`.

```
// used in onCreate() and onConfigurationChanged() to set up the UI elements
public void InitializeUI() {
    // get views from ID's
    relLayoutHeader = _______Initialise_here;
    TextView lblTitle = new TextView(myContext);
    relLayoutHeader.addView(lblTitle);
    // etc... hook up click listeners, whatever you need from the Views
}

// Called when the activity is first created.
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    InitializeUI();
}

// this is called when the screen rotates.
// (onCreate is no longer called when screen rotates due to manifest, see:
// android:configChanges)
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    InitializeUI();
    //And then do your stuff
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
           lblTitle.settext("LandScape");
   } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
       lblTitle.settext("Portrait");
   }
}
```